# The map is not displayed if you go to the site by https, but it is displayed if you go to http. Why?

Tags: google-maps

The map is not displayed if you go to the site by https, but it is displayed if you go to http.  This is what happens in chrome. Why ?

Answer (score -1):

You might be loading the Google Maps embed script hardcoded via http like `http://maps.googleapis.com/…`. Check for errors in the browser console and change to a protocol agnostic url like `//maps.googleapis.com/`

Comment: Downvoting answers or questions only helps when you add a reasoning. What's wrong here please?